# "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'. (on update cascade, on delete cascade,)

Tags: mysql

total noob sorry any help greatly appreciated. 
I keep getting this "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'." 
heres my codes

code one

```
CREATE TABLE supplier (
supplierID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ISBN INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES book(ISBN),
price DECIMAL (5,2),
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

code two

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
orderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
customerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(customerID),
ISBN INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES book(ISBN),
orderDate date,
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

Ive run out of stuff to try other than dumbing it down to uselessness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` should be besides the Foreign Key definition, not away from it. Also, each Foreign Key definition will be having its own `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE supplier (
supplierID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ISBN INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES book(ISBN) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE 
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
price DECIMAL (5,2)
);


CREATE TABLE orders (
orderID INT PRIMARY KEY,
customerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES customer(customerID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
ISBN INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES book(ISBN)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE,
orderDate date
);
```